# How do I mount my iphone 5S (iOS 9.3.2) to Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: iphone

I used to be able to browse a number of folders (music, voice memos, etc.) on my iPhone through Nautilus in 14.04. Now when I plug it in, I see only the DCIM folder with my photos in it. What has changed and how can I revert to the previous behaviour?

Edit: I am able to navigate to the folders by doing `sudo idevicepair pair` and then visiting `afc://<the long id string returned by that command>`. But I still don't know why I had to do this when it seemed to be automatic in 14.04.

Comment: Apple changed what's visible to computers most likely.  There are a lot of changes they made to the security of the device when 9.3.x came out

Comment: Info you have included in your question helped me connect Iphone 5S with Ubuntu 16.04. Thank you for informing about idevicepair !